# parse systool output into hash in perl

Tags: perl

I am tying to parse the Output of systool into perl hashes to print each found device with ist attributes and values in csv format.

```
# systool  -c fc_host -v
Class = "fc_host"

  Class Device = "host11"
    dev_loss_tmo        = "30"
    fabric_name         = "0x1000c4f57c548ba0"
    issue_lip           = <store method only>
    max_npiv_vports     = "255"
    maxframe_size       = "2048 bytes"
    node_name           = "0x20000090faf02a08"
    npiv_vports_inuse   = "0"
    port_id             = "0xcf0500"
    port_name           = "0x10000090faf02a08"
    port_state          = "Online"    supported_classes   = "Class 3"

  Class Device = "host12"
    dev_loss_tmo        = "30"
    fabric_name         = "0x1000c4f57c54a0d0"
    ....
```

I just don't know how to start to get thist structured data into a hash, or even into a list of hashes (one hash for each found HBA).
I was trying something like:

```
open (SysTool, "/usr/bin/systool -c fc_host -v |") or die "problem running systool";
while (<SysTool>) {
  %FChost  = $1 if /Class Device =:\s+"(\w+)"$/;
  ($attribute, $value) = split /=/, $_;
   $FChost{$attribute} = $value;
}
```

But it just doesn't work. :( Any idea please?

Comment: all your lines seem to have a very similar structure. why not capture with this regex `/\s*(\S+)\s+=\s+(\S+)/`. the only thing it misses is "class device"

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working, is this line:

```
%FChost  = $1 if /Class Device =:\s+"(\w+)"$/;
```

What are you intending it to do? I mean, for starters - it's never going to match given your input (there's no `:` in there) but even correcting for that you're assigning a single scalar to a hash, and that's giving you:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'host11' => undef
        };
```

It does *sort* of work otherwise, but each iteration through the loop will clobber every other record, and you don't seem to do anything with it otherwise.

Also - please `use strict; use warnings;` - it helps massively.

The thing that's useful to know here is - set `$/` to `' '` and it will work in paragraph mode.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = ''; 

while ( <> ) {
   my %record = m/(\w+)\s*=\s*\"(\S+)\"/g;
   print Dumper \%record;
}
```

And this gives you a record looking like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'node_name' => '0x20000090faf02a08',
          'port_state' => 'Online',
          'port_id' => '0xcf0500',
          'max_npiv_vports' => '255',
          'dev_loss_tmo' => '30',
          'Device' => 'host11',
          'port_name' => '0x10000090faf02a08',
          'npiv_vports_inuse' => '0',
          'fabric_name' => '0x1000c4f57c548ba0'
        };
```

Which you can then `push` into an array of records if you so desire, or print using hash-slices:

```
my @fields = qw(port_id port_name port_state);
print join ",", @record{@fields},"\n";
```

Note - you should probably also use lexical file handles and 3 arg open:

```
open ( my $systool, '-|', '/usr/bin/systool -c fc_host -v' );
```

So something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open ( my $systool, '-|', '/usr/bin/systool -c fc_host -v' ); 
local $/ = '';

my @records; 

while ( <$systool> ) {
    next unless m/Device/;
    push @records, {m/(\w+)\s*=\s*\"(\S+)\"/g};
}

#print for debug
print Dumper \@records;

my @headers = qw ( Device port_id port_name port_state );
foreach my $record ( @records ) {
   print join ",", @{$record}{@headers},"\n";
}
```

Comment: my original intention was to name the hash after the regex found in the first line you mentioned. And your're right, my hash got clobbered after each loop.
Thanks so much for your input, now I'm able to accomplish my script.